# ARMv7 assembler merges two constant strings for no reason

Tags: gcc, arm, compiler-construction, armv7

I have the following ARMv7 code:

```
.section .text
.global main

main:
        ldr r1, =str1   // load only the first string
        ldr r2, =_len0  // load the length of str1

        mov r0, #1 // sets output to stdout
        mov r7, #4 // print
        swi 0      // interruption

        mov r7, #1 // exit code
        swi 0      // interruption

.section .data
str1: .string "hello1\n"

str2: .string "hello2\n"

_len0 = .-str1
```

This code should only print the first string (hello1) but it seems to be merging the two strings and when I run it with qemu it shows this:

```
hello1
hello2
```

What's happening? If I put the length constant between the two strings it correctly prints just the first string

```
str1: .string "hello1\n"

_len0 = .-str1

str2: .string "hello2\n"
```

```
hello1
```

I'm using the following tooling for assemble and link it:

```
$ arm-linux-gnueabi-as print.s -o print.o 

$ arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc-9 print.o -o print.elf -nostdlib --entry main

$ qemu-arm ./print.elf
```

Comment: But in the first example you set the length equal to the length of both strings combined. Why should it print only the first string?

Comment: _len0 = .-str1 isn't just the first string length? why it points for both? Thank you so much, I'm just learning ARM and obviously missing something ...

Comment: That expression would give you the length of the first string *if* it is evaluated directly after that string (so that the current position, `.`, is directly after the string), but if you put more stuff in between then that gets counted as well

Comment: What makes you think that `_len0 = .-str1` calculates the length of the first string?

Comment: I didn't know the expression would count all the symbols previously defined. I was thinking that the .-str1 refers only to the first string (str1) just because ends with the same name. But I guess that it is only a subtraction of the memory point right there. Thank you both!

Comment: `str1` does indeed refer to the start of first string. You are calculating the difference between `str1` (the start of the first string) and `.` (the current location). So it calculates the length of the string that starts at `str1` and ends at the current location. That length naturally depends on the location at which you perform the calculation.